# shouldAutorotate() function in Xcode 8 beta 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I updated Xcode 8 beta 3 to Xcode 8 beta 4 and I am actually correcting some bugs due to swift changement.

Function :

```
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Print an error and Xcode told me that this function is not override. It's mean that the function does not exist anymore.

```
override var shouldAutorotate
```

This var has just get properties so I can't change the value by this way.

So how can I work with autorotate now ?

Thanks !

Comment: self.shouldAutorotate = false ?

Comment: As I said, it's a get-properties so I can't change the value by this way ;)

Comment: what does Xcode trying to autocomplete when you start typing shouldAuto...? error say that it is just not override anymore not that it does not exist anymore

Comment: I looked inside the definition of UIViewController and I didn't find the function.
It's only get me "ShouldAutorotate: Bool"
"ShouldAutomaticallyForwardAppaeranceMethod: Bool"
And
"Should ShouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethod() -> Bool"

Comment: It is just specific view, I already set my parameters into my settings project ;)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is the right way

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3 Syntax

```
open override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    get {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
open override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .landscape
}

open override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}
```